# IntelliJ idea copy file automatically

Tags: intellij-idea

When I use idea to develop java project, I found that the java source file was copied. Just like follows:

```
// my java source files in the src dir
demo.java

// after it was copied
demo.java   demo 2.java    demo 3.java
```

Then I will failed to build my project.

Anybody can help me? Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, it's quite unclear what you want to ask. Does this happens with all your projects? Does the duplication happens after build the project? Please, provide more information about the steps that you are following and your version of intelliJ, it would be useful to point you in he correct direction. Thanks!

Comment: My idea version is 2019.3.1. My project is built by `mvn compile` and then I run the one test by idea. After I run the test, the source file is duplicated sometime. But I can not see what time the duplication happened. I just import the project into  my idea without setting anything except the java version to use.

Comment: Maybe my icloud results to the duplication. I will confirm it